# How can I get my zend application working as a subdirectory of a domain?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a domain with ssl (canvas.example.com), and have created a new zend application that I want to add to that domain (canvas.example.com/newapp). It is on an apache server. Is this possible? I have tried to modify my virtual host, and also played with .htaccess, but no luck. Perhaps some route rules in Zend could get this working, I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default Zend_Application `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

You need to tell `mod_rewrite` what the base directory is, using `RewriteBase`, like so:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newapp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

(Where this file goes in the same directory as your index.php)

This is the only zend specific thing going on; everything else should be just as configuring a vhost in apache.